# Identify recource name & extension from weburl in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]paste below url in chrome and chrome will give you exact filename with extension.

https://www.videvo.net/download_new.php?hash=f654a8d8307038ae523769b502f35ab5&test_new_server=1

like chrome knows the name & extension, I want to do this with swift.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Use `URLComponents`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using `downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename` from below `func`

```
 func URLSession(session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        print(downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename as Any)
        print(downloadTask.response?.mimeType as Any)

    }
```